# Best way to display something live with jQuery

Tags: jquery, canvas

So, i have a function for retrieve current FPS on the current canva : `getMeasuredFPS()`

This function return a number.

What is the best way for display this information in live ?

Create a div and refresh this div every second ? I don't think...

Comment: That sounds like a good approach. You could also have a `input` field and update that every second. It's likely to be more or less the same performance-wise though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something even cooler.. like doing a 'stats' bar that will show a visual of the frame rate.  So you can see spikes, and valleys.

https://github.com/mrdoob/stats.js